# How to pass optional query parameters with groovy?

Tags: groovy, micronaut

I would like to pass optional params to url using micronaut with groovy. I did lots of research but was not able to find any relevant answer.

```
@Get('/product/{country}/?
```

I would like to pass in sort and date as optional parameters to this url.
Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass optional sort and date parameters as query values like this:

```
@Controller('/')
@CompileStatic
class WithOptionalParameterController {
    @Get('/product/{country}{?sort,date}')
    String productsForCountry(String country, 
                              @Nullable @Pattern(regexp = 'code|title') String sort, 
                              @Nullable String date) {
        "Products for $country sorted by $sort and there is also date $date."
    }
}
```

And it can be called this way with sort and date specified:

```
$ curl 'http://localhost:8080/product/chile?sort=code&date=23.3.2020'
Products for chile sorted by code and there is also date 23.3.2020.
```

Or without date:

```
$ curl 'http://localhost:8080/product/chile?sort=code'
Products for chile sorted by code and there is also date null.
```

Or without sort and date:

```
$ curl 'http://localhost:8080/product/chile'
Products for chile sorted by null and there is also date null.
```

---

Example for POST where you have to add `@QueryValue` annotation for query parameters:

```
@Consumes([MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN])
@Post('/product/{country}{?sort,date}')
String productsForCountry(String country, 
                          @Nullable @Pattern(regexp = 'code|title') @QueryValue String sort,
                          @Nullable @QueryValue String date,
                          @Body String body) {
    "Products for $country sorted by $sort and there is also date $date. Body is $body."
}
```

And it can be called this way:

```
$ curl -X POST 'http://localhost:8080/product/chile?sort=code&date=23.3.2020' -H "Content-Type: text/plain" -d 'some body'
Products for chile sorted by code and there is also date 23.3.2020. Body is some body.
```

Comment: great! Thanks this works. Is there any way to pass parameters with @Post request?

Comment: I added also example for POST request. You have to add the `@QueryValue` annotation for query parameters, otherwise it will try to load them from body.

Answer (score 1):

use Optional annotation , like

```
@Get("/optional")
String optional(@QueryValue Optional<Integer> max) {
  return "Parameter Value: " + max.orElse(10);
}
```